# Kendo Grid - Maintain headings when scrolling vertically

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid (version 2012.3.1114) that displays quite a bit of data.

The grid scrolls vertically and does not page, as this is a requirement we have.

Is there any way that the grid can maintain it's headings visible as the user scrolls down? I'm looking for something similar to how Excel behaves when you select the "Freeze Top Row" option.

Comment: How did you resolved your issue, I have the same problem too please post the answer plz

Comment: @user1016740 I had to give my kendo grid a fixed height based on the window height of the browser. I did this by setting the height property of the grid like so: height: function () { return $(window).height() - $('#myGrid')[0].offsetTop - 70; }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the height of the table body as follow

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: datasource,
    pageable  : false,
    height:     300,
    columns   : [
        ...
    ]
});
```

*NOTE*: The height is the height in pixels of the body of the table (does not include header or footer).

Comment: Ok I see what you're proposing. In my case the height of the grid will have to be dynamically calculated depending on the height of the window. So then the contents of the grid will scroll and not the contents of the window. This way I won't have 2 vertical scrollbars on the page.